Calling decorator returns output of original function
i need to know why the output of this code is sayhello() only???
def myDecorator(func):  # Decorator

    def nestedfunc():  # Any Name Its Just For Decoration
        print("Before")  # Message From Decorator

        func()  # Execute Function

        print("After")  # Message From Decorator

    return nestedfunc  # Return All Data


def sayHello():
    print("Hello from sayHello function")


myDecorator(sayHello())


Note that @decorator def f(): ... is equivalent to decorator(f), not decorator(f()). See also the related docs: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions

myDecorator(sayHello()) calls sayHello() which returns None and then calls myDecorator(None) which returns the nestedfunc which isn't actually called.
Use the following to decorate your function and call it:
def myDecorator(func):
    def nestedfunc():
        print("Before")
        func()
        print("After")
    return nestedfunc

@myDecorator  # correct decorator syntax
def sayHello():
    print("Hello from sayHello function")

sayHello()

Output:
Before
Hello from sayHello function
After

The decorator(@) syntax is equivalent to the following:
def myDecorator(func):
    def nestedfunc():
        print("Before")
        func()
        print("After")
    return nestedfunc

def sayHello():
    print("Hello from sayHello function")

# Pass sayHello as the func parameter to MyDecorator
# and return nestedfunc.  Reassign to sayHello.
sayHello = myDecorator(sayHello)

sayHello()  # now really calling nestedfunc.


With myDecorator(sayHello()) you first run the sayHello() function which prints "Hello from sayHello function" and returns None.
Then this None is passed to myDecorator() which returns the nestedfunc. You don't run this function. If you'd run this function you would get an error.
